# JQuery: How to append element after and element appears with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that is loaded via AJAX (I have no access to the JS files that trigger this).

I want to use JQuery to append some HTML to the body of the modal.

If course I can't simply do that within a document.ready function.

Is there a way to append the HTML when another element appears in the DOM?

I've tried

```
    $('.npopup .description').load(function(){
        $(this).append(message);
    });
```

and

```
    $('.npopup .description').ready(function(){
        $(this).append(message);
    });
```

with no results.

Comment: Depending on the library used to show the modal, there might be an event you can listen for. For example, Bootstrap has the [`shown.bs.modal` event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

Comment: after `ajaxStop` or `ajaxComplete` you can find element and if found, based on that you can append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `ajaxComplete()` like that:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $(this).append(message);
  }
});
```

Make sure you give a look at the `event`, `xhr` and `settings` to let you find what request you are interested in. Otherwise, if you don't use the `if` statement in the body of the callback, you will append the message in every ajax call.

Another possible solution is to listen for changes in the DOM using the MutationObserver. See for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver.

The MutationObserver is a better solution though, but I don't remember what is the compatibility with the browsers. Generally speaking, the compatibility is quite good.